# My controller returns ModelAndView but it doesn't load jsp

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm studying the restful API. In this project, I wanna log-in using restful API. So, I made two projects. The one is spring MVC. It just shows the web page. Another is the restful API. And It worked well but when I call the web page, it doesn't work.

I found several solutions, but those not for me.
The one checks `import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`. I already used it.
Another used String as the return type in the controller instead of ModelAndView.

This is my Controller.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayWelcom(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        System.out.println("Welcome model");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

And This is my javascript for going to another page(welcome).

```
function validateForm() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/users/www.t3q.com";
        //      + window.location.hostname;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert('1');
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
//              if(json.isSuccess == 'true')
//              {
                    var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp2.open("GET", "http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCloginExample/welcome", true);
                    xmlhttp2.send();
//              } else {
//                  alert(json.reason);
//              }
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        var userData = JSON.stringify($("#loginForm").serializeObject());

        console.log(userData);
        xmlhttp.send(userData);
    }
```

And This is my spring web setting XML.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.t3q" />

<!--    <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

And this is web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringMVCloginExample</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath://resource//springWeb.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Actually, I already used `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.
How can I solve this problem?
Help me, please.

---

Additional 1.
This is my project explorer.

[image]

---

Answer (modified)

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"localhost:8080/welcome");
$(document.body).append(f);
f.submit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"localhost:8080/welcome");
$(document.body).append(f);
f.submit();
```

Comment: I added my project explorer in the post. And it works well when I access the web page using URL in the browser.

Comment: Are you trying to open a page through ajax call ? In that case it will not happen.
It is something like an ajax call waits for a response from the server(Which is different from submitting a form) .

Comment: Ah... thanks. I understand. Then, To go to the welcome page, how what I do?

Comment: You can create a form in your JS code, submit that form through JS and then the controller will open you JSP.

some thing like this
   var f = document.createElement("form");
   f.setAttribute('method',"post");
   f.setAttribute('action',"localhost:8080/welcome");
   f.submit()

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. When I use it, it works well! But I added the code like following:
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"localhost:8080/welcome");
$(document.body).append(f);
f.submit();